# Is this possible to decompose 2 arbitrary unitary matrices as: $U_{1}=ADB^{\dagger},U_{2}=BDA^{\dagger}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, matrix-decomposition

I guess this statement is true, but I can't prove it:

"For any 2 arbitrary unitary matrices $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$, we can always decompose them into $U_{1}=ADB^{\dagger},U_{2}=BDA^{\dagger}$, where $A$ and $B$ are unitary, and $D$ is diagonal."

Please prove or disprove it. It's good enough to discuss this statement by $2\times2$ matrices.

And the discussion with any of the following constraints is also helpful:

1. $U_{1}\neq U_{2}$;
2. $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ are nondegenerate;
3. $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ have no common eigenvalue;

Comment: Assume that it is true and compute $U_1 U_2$. This should give you a hint on how $A$ and $D^2$ have to look like.

Comment: (1/3)The solution space of $\begin{cases}
U_{1}U_{2} & =AD^{2}A^{\dagger}\\
U_{2}U_{1} & =BD^{2}B^{\dagger}
\end{cases}$ seems to be larger than the solution space of $\begin{cases}
U_{1} & =ADA^{\dagger}\\
U_{2} & =BDA^{\dagger}
\end{cases}$. 

For example,

 $U_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{-ik_{x}} & 0\\
0 & ie^{ik_{y}}
\end{array}\right)$ and  $U_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{ik_{x}} & 0\\
0 & ie^{-ik_{y}}
\end{array}\right)$ give 

$U_{1}U_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)$, and $U_{2}U_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: (2/3)Solving $\begin{cases}
U_{1}U_{2} & =AD^{2}A^{\dagger}\\
U_{2}U_{1} & =BD^{2}B^{\dagger}
\end{cases}$ will give us many solutions, let's pick two of them:


$D_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & i
\end{array}\right)$, $A_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$, $B_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$;

$D_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & i
\end{array}\right)$, $A_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$, $B_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{ik_{x}} & 0\\
0 & e^{-ik_{y}}
\end{array}\right)$;

Comment: (3/3)The first solution doesn't work for $\begin{cases}
U_{1} & =ADA^{\dagger}\\
U_{2} & =BDA^{\dagger}
\end{cases}$,  and the second solution works.
I was stopped by this problem when I tried this method, since the existence of the larger solution space doesn't guarantee the existence of the smaller solution space. How to continue? Add some constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by a comment, you may first *unitarily* diagonalise $U_1U_2$ as $A D^2 A^\dagger$. Since $U_1U_2$ is a unitary matrix, the eigenvalue matrix $D^2$ is unitary too. Now *define* $B = U_1^\dagger AD$, where $D$ is an entrywise square root of $D^2$. Then we are done.